# Why are these different Android maximum upload and download speeds?

Tags: 4g, network-signal

The following screenshot is from Realme 8 which has a max UL/DL of 15000/30000.

[image]

The next screenshot is from Asus Zenfone Max Pro (M2) which has a max UL/DL of 51200/102400.

[image]

The problem I am facing in my Android is this - After some time using 4G, the sign shows 4G but the speed drops to 0.01kbps. This goes on frequently until I reset the network by firstly selecting 3G/2G and then selecting 4G/3G/2G.

Can I edit these values using ADB shell so that I can set 51200/102400 as the max UL/DL value in my Android? Can someone provide any fix to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the different maximum up/dl speed are a result of different LTE implementations. LTE exists in quite a few versions with different capabilities regarding the maximum transmission speed and how many channels can be aggregated.

For example the value DL/UL as 102400/51200 seems to be LTE Cat 3 (100 Mbit/s   down, 50 Mbit/s up).

My guess is that you can't change it because the value depends on the used LTE hardware in the phone (and of course the used mobile network).

Last but not least some data plans limit the maximum download/upload speed. The values shown by your Realme 8 30MBit down and 15MBit/s to not correspond to an LTE category. The next matching one would be LTE Cat 2 with 50 Mbit/s down and 25 Mbit/s up. So most likely this is a limitation of the used data plan or the phone shows the effective transmission speed which is limited by the signal strength.

Conclusion: No you can't change the values via adb as this is either a hardware limitation by your phone, the mobile network or of your data plan.